# PHP: get path to php directory

Tags: php

default cron command:

```
00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/john/myscript.php
```

Is there a way to get with PHP the "/usr/local/bin/php" part?

Comment: `$str = '/usr/local/bin/php';` what are you asking here?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP 5.4 or above, you can use the predefined constant PHP_BINARY to get that.

If you're using PHP 5.3 or prior you could try using PHP_BINDIR, to which you'll have to append the executable filename.

See [reserved constants](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)

Comment: Thanks, but i using 5.3

Comment: See my edition. You could probably use PHP_BINDIR and append the executable filename to it. You would need to check what OS are you running on to figure that out.